# Which C# method names should not be obfuscated?

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I'm working on a C# obfuscation program, and I'm wondering if there are method names that are "hardwired" into the framework and should therefore not be modified. The ones that spring to mind are .ctor, .cctor and Dispose. Are there any others I should avoid modifying?

Edit:
To elaborate, and inspired by Paul Alexander (thanks for your answer), I'm doing this by modifying the IL source code. Here are some typical(?) .method statements:

```
  .method family hidebysig virtual instance void 
          Dispose(bool disposing) cil managed

  .method private hidebysig instance void 
          InitializeComponent() cil managed

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string> twoLetterWords) cil managed

  .method private hidebysig static string[] 
          CreateStringArray() cil managed
```

I can see that the constructor (.ctor) has a "rtspecialname" option, and Dispose has a "family" option. Is this the sort of thing I should be looking out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta data for a given method contains a "special name" flag on methods that cannot be renamed which you can use as a basic heuristic. However to accurately determine the eligibility of a method you have to walk the entire inheritance tree, accounting base classes, interfaces, methods/properties referenced by attribute strings, etc.

Comment: All of the answers were useful, but I'm selecting this one as the most insightful, along with Paul Alexander's comment about get_ and set_ on another answer. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely avoid modifying any public method in a public class. Also avoid modifying property getters and setters (`get_XXX` and `set_XXX` methods).

Comment: Good point regarding get_xxx and set_xxx, thanks. As for public method names in public classes, I do intend to modify them - and then to take this into account when processing references from other classes and assemblies. Any other method names that should be left alone?

Comment: get_XXX and set_XXX are actually safe to obfuscate. The .NET runtime can resolve the methods for properties just fine even when obfuscated - this is true even when using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Don't obfuscate anything to do with serialization unless the names are explicitly stated via attributes; and even then take care - some serializers include type names in the metadata (which may not match for long).

Watch out for convention-based methods; for example `ShouldSerializeFoo()` and `ResetFoo()` (twinned with property `Foo`) - these conventions are common in both serializers and the `ComponentModel`. There is also a `FooHasValue` convention for some serializers.

And anything that is going to use reflection is likely doomed... ;p

Answer (score 1):

More on methods/classes used via reflection: beware of framework or target application using reflection to dicover types and methods. I.e. in ASP.Net MVC classes for processing requests are picked up by name, in SharePoint a lot of third party classes are referenced by name - as result one should not obfuscate particular class names in assembly to be used with such application.

I'd go with approach other obfuscators are using - custom attributes to control obfuscation and separate externally configurable lists of classes/methods that should not be obfuscated. It is impossible to correctly guess what methods can and cannot be obfuscated in general case. I.e. obfuscating public method names is possible only if you know all callers - not always the case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "obfuscating public method names is possible only if you know all callers" - I do know all callers - this is my own program and I have full control over all parts of it, even though it is a multi-assembly program.

Answer (score 1):

There are many criteria which should be used to determine when methods should not be renamed:

- Methods overridding virtual methods from the .Net Base Class Library.
- ctor and cctor
- Methods marked specialName and rtSpecialName and runtime.

and some more like exlcuding public methods if obfuscating a dll.

BTW, I am curious as to whether you are doing this as a learning experience or for your own use. If the latter, I would tell you that its better to use a commercial obfuscator instead of spending time on this (focus on your core functionality instead!).

Disclaimer: I work at LogicNP Software, the developers of [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm)

Comment: "If the latter, I would tell you that its better to use a commercial obfuscator instead of spending time on this" - What? And miss out on all this fun? BTW, thanks for your answer.